# Tables have same style but show different

Tags: css, html, html-table

I have two tables which one of them is like header and fix at the top of the another one.
they have same style just the font size and the content of them is different,but when I run the page in the local I see that the width I gave to first table is 2 pix more than the second one. I use reset.css and also give `table-layout:fix`. can anyone help me with this problem?

**html:**

```
<div class="first extras" id="first">
      <table id="headtable">
          <tr>
            <td class="diff1">نام سرور</td>
            <td class="diff2">CPU</td>
            <td class="diff3">RAM</td>
            <td class="diff4">hard</td>
            <td class="diff5">فضا</td>
            <td class="diff6">پهنای باند</td>
            <td class="diff7">db1</td>
            <td class="diff8">data</td>
            <td class="diff9">ext</td>
            <td class="diff10">db2</td>
            <td class="diff11">os</td>
            <td class="proo diff12"></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
</div>
<div class="hole" id="hole">
      <table id="panels-compare" class="tahoma compare panels">
        <tr>
            <td width="60">ایران۷</td>
            <td width="40">Xeon 3430</td>
            <td width="40">۸ گیگابایت</td>
            <td width="37">SATA</td>
            <td width="60">2x500GB</td>
            <td width="43">۱۰۰ مگابیت</td>
            <td width="48">۱۰۰ گیگابایت</td>
            <td width="50">pars</td>
            <td width="41">pars1</td>
            <td width="45">۵۰,۰۰۰</td>
            <td width="45">۳۵۰,۰۰۰</td>
            <td width="90">order</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ایران۱۴</td>
            <td>2xXeon 5520</td>
            <td>۱۶ گیگابایت</td>
            <td>SATA</td>
            <td>2x1TB</td>
            <td>۱۰۰ مگابیت</td>
            <td>۲۰۰ گیگابایت</td>
            <td>pars</td>
            <td>pars1</td>
            <td>۵۰,۰۰۰</td>
            <td>۴۹۰,۰۰۰</td>
            <td>order</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ایران۱۵</td>
            <td>Xeon 3430</td>
            <td>۳۲ گیگابایت</td>
            <td>SATA</td>
            <td>2x1TB</td>
            <td>۱۰۰ مگابیت</td>
            <td>۳ ترابایت</td>
            <td>pars></td>
            <td>pars1</td>
            <td>۵۰,۰۰۰</td>
            <td>۳۹۰,۰۰۰</td>
            <td>order</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.first {
  width: 980px;
  z-index: 1000;
 }
.extras {
  height: 65px !important;
 }
 .extras #headtable {
   table-layout: fixed;
 }
 #headtable,#panels-compare{
   line-height: 18px;
   width: 980px;
   border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 td:first-child {
  font-size: 18px !important;
 }
 #panels tr td:first-child, #headtable tr td:first-child {
  font-family: 'Yekan'
 }
 #headtable td:first-child, #panels-compare td:first-child{
  border-right: none !important;
 }
 #headtable td, #panels td, #panels2 td, #panels-compare td{
  border-right: 3px solid #fff;
  font-size: 13.294px;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #616161;
  border-color: #fff;
  }
 .diff1 {
  width: 60px;
  padding: 5px 7px !important;
 }
 #headtable tr:first-child td {
  font-size: 18px;
 }
 .diff2{
  width:40px; 
 }

 .diff3{
  width:40px; 
 }

 .diff4{
  width:37px; 
 }
.diff5{
  width:60px; 
 }   
.diff6{
  width:43px; 
 }

.diff7{
 width:48px; 
}
.diff8{
 width:50px; 
}
.diff9{
 width:41px; 
}
.diff10{
 width:45px; 
}
.diff11{
 width:45px; 
}
.diff12{
width: 90px;
}
#panels-compare td:first-child {
padding: 5px 7px !important;
}
.compare {
 table-layout: fixed;
 }
.panels {
 border-top: none !important;
 }
```

I don't upload the changes yet, but if you want to know how is the main layout, you can see this [link](http://www.iranserver.com/new/dedicated-server/compare/).

Comment: You should make the table headings part of the table instead of having 2 separate tables.

Comment: ur actual code and what u paste here seems to use different code.. as this pasted code seems to work fine having same width  http://jsfiddle.net/4ZPr5/

Comment: @BillyJ. when page scroll, I want to first table be fixed so I used two tables

Comment: @cjmling yes, code doesn't upload yet so style-sheet are different. yes in jsfiddle seems to work well!!! perhaps I don't copy some part of my css codes.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the same width for each td on header table. Then assign break-word css property for each table column.

```
<div class="first extras" id="first">
  <table id="headtable">
      <tr>
        <td class="diff1" width="60">نام سرور</td>
        <td class="diff2" width="40">CPU</td>
        <td class="diff3" width="40">RAM</td>
        <td class="diff4" width="37">hard</td>
        <td class="diff5" width="60">فضا</td>
        <td class="diff6" width="43">پهنای باند</td>
        <td class="diff7" width="48">db1</td>
        <td class="diff8" width="50">data</td>
        <td class="diff9" width="41">ext</td>
        <td class="diff10" width="45">db2</td>
        <td class="diff11" width="45">os</td>
        <td class="proo diff12" width="90"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="hole" id="hole">
  <table id="panels-compare" class="tahoma compare panels">
    <tr>
        <td width="60">ایران۷</td>
        <td width="40">Xeon 3430</td>
        <td width="40">۸ گیگابایت</td>
        <td width="37">SATA</td>
        <td width="60">2x500GB</td>
        <td width="43">۱۰۰ مگابیت</td>
        <td width="48">۱۰۰ گیگابایت</td>
        <td width="50">pars</td>
        <td width="41">pars1</td>
        <td width="45">۵۰,۰۰۰</td>
        <td width="45">۳۵۰,۰۰۰</td>
        <td width="90">order</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ایران۱۴</td>
        <td>2xXeon 5520</td>
        <td>۱۶ گیگابایت</td>
        <td>SATA</td>
        <td>2x1TB</td>
        <td>۱۰۰ مگابیت</td>
        <td>۲۰۰ گیگابایت</td>
        <td>pars</td>
        <td>pars1</td>
        <td>۵۰,۰۰۰</td>
        <td>۴۹۰,۰۰۰</td>
        <td>order</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ایران۱۵</td>
        <td>Xeon 3430</td>
        <td>۳۲ گیگابایت</td>
        <td>SATA</td>
        <td>2x1TB</td>
        <td>۱۰۰ مگابیت</td>
        <td>۳ ترابایت</td>
        <td>pars></td>
        <td>pars1</td>
        <td>۵۰,۰۰۰</td>
        <td>۳۹۰,۰۰۰</td>
        <td>order</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Add this class in your css

```
#headtable td, #panels-compare td
{
word-wrap:break-word !important;
}
```

The above code will align your header and contents in a same line.